# Need to return from mail composing page to specific activity

Tags: android

enter code hereI am using mail composing option from my app i.e when i click on submit button i am navigating  the user to the mail composing page.
Now i want to return to a specific activity on either case 
1- on success full send . navigate to activity2
2- on Discard navigate to activity1

how can i do that 
the code is following

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { 

"sales@fastpkg.com"});

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Placing an Order");

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is a 

sample mail..");

emailIntent.setType("text/plain");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail client :"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, if you use

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail client :"),RESULT_OK);
```

You can always navigate to your activity (Land at `onActivityResult()` of your current Activity) from which you have started the above activity either **its success** or when you **press back key** from started activity.

Comment: can you give a code example of onActivityResult() as its not working when i press back button it returns to that activity from where in app composer page opens i need to return to home page/activity

Comment: "when i press back button it returns to that activity from where in app composer page opens" - obviously desired behavior, for return to Home activity you have to implement some logic on your onActivityResult()